# How do I make inline code blocks for my application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How should I go about implementing a way for a user in my app, to insert a inline code block similar to how you can in Notion or Obsidian? I don't know whether there is a simple library I can use in my react app that I could imbed it into a text area, or if I should make something from scratch. Also how should I make it so users can add a code block, should it be a tactile button or a syntax trigger? [Obsidian Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKmkJ.png) | [Notion Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVhbb.png) | [My Current Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERJAW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve the required functionality of code block using a widely used package `highlight.js`.

The package highlights the code block inside `<code>` tag. If you are using markdown, it would automatically convert '```' into code blocks and then you can use `highlight.js` for syntax highlighting.

I recently worked on a project where I implemented this functionality. You can refer this [website](https://interviewmogul.com).

npm package for highlight.js - [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highlight.js?activeTab=readme)